# How can i count time of power on

Tags: pi-3

I'm using Raspberry Pi 3 , and i want to count the time of Power-on for electricity generator by intercepting the power circuit .

how i can do and what is the needed components

Comment: This question is likely to get deleted without clarification on what you are trying to do. Things like how you plan on reporting the data, what you are trying sense (how long it takes to switch from mains to backup generator?) the electrical specifications. Required accuracy would also be helpful (this will tell you if you need to use interrupts, pooling or even a bare metal application).

Answer (score 1):

> Uptime

That'll give you how long the R-Pi has been powered on for. If that's what you are asking.